# Change div color on rightclick

Tags: function, onclick, click, mouseevent

Can you help me change this function to work on rightclick?

I have been trying to use an if statement but have had no luck.

```
function change(elm){
    elm.style.backgroundColor = '#A9A9A9', elm.innerHTML = "OFF", 
    elm.style.fontSize= "10px", elm.style.paddingTop = "10px";
}
```

Comment: in the real code did you use commas? Please replace with semi colon's and lets see

Comment: You will probably find that the parameter passed to the function is an event, not an element. you may need to use elm.target to get to the HTML object

Answer (score 0):

Change HTML to oncontextmenu

```
<button oncontextmenu="change(elm)"></button>
```

Comment: Hey, the function works fine on left click but what I am trying to do is change it work on the right click

Comment: I am not sure how I mislead you? my question is asking to change the function to work on right click instead of left..

Comment: You pasted the code of the function and that's what mislead us, even the rightclick was not emphasised

Comment: I pasted the code and the message before it asks to help me make it work on rightclick. Think you mislead yourself mate

Comment: Hey there @SamLawless -- it seems surge10 has updated their answer. Check out the new version which uses `oncontextmenu`, which should properly trigger your function on right click. If that solves your problem, feel free to mark this answer as the solution to the problem. If  not, feel free to let us know or to update your question so we may help you out!